# RNADE vs MDR vs BART vs Bayesian Linear Regression

Tags: neural-network, regression, linear-regression, bayesian

I'm looking at a collection of problems where I need to forecast the probability of a continuous variable. My dependent variables are a combination of categorical and continuous. It looks like there are four primary candidate areas I should be reviewing and/or testing. Can anyone here shed any light on the relative strengths and risks associated with each of RNADE, Mixture Density Networks, Bayesian Additive Regression Trees, and standard Bayesian Linear Regression?

Comment: Is your data a time series? The reason I ask is because you use the word 'forecast'.

Comment: Time is a feature of the dataset but it's only a weak predictor.